# Calling a function in select statement

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have a function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION numOfOrders(name VARCHAR2) RETURN sys_refcursor AS
  test_cur sys_refcursor;
BEGIN
  OPEN test_cur for
  
    SELECT C_CustKey, C_Name, COUNT(*) AS Num_Of_Orders
      FROM Customer c
     INNER JOIN Orders o
        ON o.O_CustKey = c.C_CustKey
     WHERE C_Name = name
     GROUP BY C_CustKey, C_Name;

  RETURN test_cur;
END;
/
```

the screenshot of the code :

[image]

and i called it by typing

```
SELECT numOfOrders('john') FROM customer;
```

I get my intended output:

```
C_CustKey    C_Name     Num_Of_Orders 
0001         john        10
```

but it gets repeated for the number of rows in my customer table, i can fix this by adding fetch first 1 rows only; but how do I prevent it from happening.

Link to output (I can assure you all 1214 rows are the same) :

[image]

**Tables**

*Customer* :
[image]

*Orders* :
[image]

Comment: That most certainly isn't code you ran because it is invalid (hint: INTO clause in SELECT statement, missing semi-colon as a statement terminator). I suggest you post both tables' description and real code. As of your question: that usually happens when people name parameter with the same name as the column name so there's no filtering at all.

Comment: my bad i am running it in ubuntu and couldn't copy the latest working code, copied and pasted what i thought was the latest version stored in my notepad++

Comment: As you probably guess, it is pointless debugging code you actually don't use. Do post tables' description and your latest code (and its outcome - not *all* duplicate rows, just a few if there really are duplicates).

Comment: This is because you are calling the function with the same argument value for each row. But it would be **much** better (in terms of supportability, readability and performance) to use plain join instead of function, especially with`cursor` as return type.

Comment: okay added the screenshots, unfortunately I have to implement this using a function, and i guess the fix is to type "fetch first 1 rows only' but just wanna know if there is a better way

Comment: What do you want to achieve as a result? Obviously, without `where` clause you'll always have all the rows of a table in the output. But it is not clear why you are selecting a function call with constant value from some table and why you are using a cursor (to be more specific, why you are trying to return three columns instead of just `count`). Cursor will not "print" something in pure SQL, it will be a cursor object, which you need to process. In SQL\*Plus the tool does this for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To cut a long story short: this is wrong:

```
select numOfOrders('john') from customer;
                                --------
                                this
```

because you're selecting the same dataset for **all rows in `customer` table**. What would be better? This:

```
select numOfOrders('john') from dual;
                                ----
                                this
```

Why `dual`? Because it contains only one row.

---

A simple example based on Scott's schema (I don't have your data): there are 14 employees in the whole `emp` table, some of them working in department 10.

Function, similar to yours:

```
SQL> create or replace function num_of_employees (p_deptno in dept.deptno%type)
  2    return sys_refcursor
  3  is
  4    l_rc sys_refcursor;
  5  begin
  6    open l_rc for
  7      select d.dname,
  8             count(*) as num_of_employees
  9      from dept d join emp e on e.deptno = d.deptno
 10      where d.deptno = p_deptno
 11      group by d.dname;
 12    return l_rc;
 13  end;
 14  /

Function created.
```

This is what you should do - select from `dual`; the result is just a single line:

```
SQL> select num_of_employees(10) from dual;

NUM_OF_EMPLOYEES(10)
--------------------
CURSOR STATEMENT : 1

CURSOR STATEMENT : 1

DNAME          NUM_OF_EMPLOYEES
-------------- ----------------
ACCOUNTING                    3          --> this is the result

SQL>
```

---

But, if you select from `emp` (which has 14 rows), you'll get 14 *duplicate* rows as the result:

```
SQL> select num_of_employees(10) from emp;

NUM_OF_EMPLOYEES(10)
--------------------
CURSOR STATEMENT : 1

CURSOR STATEMENT : 1

DNAME          NUM_OF_EMPLOYEES
-------------- ----------------
ACCOUNTING                    3

CURSOR STATEMENT : 1

CURSOR STATEMENT : 1

DNAME          NUM_OF_EMPLOYEES
-------------- ----------------
ACCOUNTING                    3

CURSOR STATEMENT : 1

CURSOR STATEMENT : 1

DNAME          NUM_OF_EMPLOYEES
-------------- ----------------
ACCOUNTING                    3

<snip>    

14 rows selected.

SQL>
```

---

You asked whether it'll work (the `dual` table) if function returns more than a single row: it will.

I modified the function so that - if no department is passed to the function - it returns number of employees in *all* departments (i.e. multiple rows):

```
SQL> create or replace function num_of_employees (p_deptno in dept.deptno%type)
  2    return sys_refcursor
  3  is
  4    l_rc sys_refcursor;
  5  begin
  6    open l_rc for
  7      select d.dname,
  8             count(*) as num_of_employees
  9      from dept d join emp e on e.deptno = d.deptno
 10      where d.deptno = p_deptno or p_deptno is null   --> modified WHERE clause
 11      group by d.dname;
 12    return l_rc;
 13  end;
 14  /

Function created.
```

Calling the function:

```
SQL> select num_of_employees(null) from dual;

NUM_OF_EMPLOYEES(NUL
--------------------
CURSOR STATEMENT : 1

CURSOR STATEMENT : 1

DNAME          NUM_OF_EMPLOYEES
-------------- ----------------
ACCOUNTING                    3
RESEARCH                      5
SALES                         6


SQL>
```

Comment: yes thank you now it works! However just to check does dual still work when I am returning multiple rows?

Comment: You're welcome. It'll work, no problem; I edited the answer and added an example which demonstrates it - have a look.